# react-router how to build app structure?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I still search for a tutorial which explains how to build a structure for the following scenario

- on app boot `/` I have all listed items
- click on specific item redirects to a new route /itemid and shows item details

till now my structure

```
app
-- dist
-- src
--- components
---- Layout.js
---- Items.js
---- Item.js
--- actions
--- stores
--- dispatchers
--- services
-- styles
Root.js
App.js
index.js
webpack.config.js
package.json
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { createHistory, createHashHistory } from 'history';
import Root from './Root';

const rootEl = document.getElementById('workshop-booker');
// Use hash location for Workshop Pages
// but switch to HTML5 history locally.
const history = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ?
    createHashHistory() :
    createHistory();

React.render(<Root history={history} />, rootEl);
```

Root.js

```
import React, { PropTypes, Component } from 'react';
import { Router, Route } from 'react-router';

import App from './App';
import Workshops from './components/Workshops';
import Workshop from './components/Workshop';

export default class Root extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        history: PropTypes.object.isRequired
    }

    render() {
        const { history } = this.props;
        return (
            <Router history={history}>
                <Route name='workshops' path='/' component={App}>
                    <Route name='workshop' path='/:slug' component={Workshop} />
                </Route>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}
```

App.js

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import Layout from './components/Layout';
import DocumentTitle from 'react-document-title';

export default class App {
    static propTypes = {
        children: PropTypes.object
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <DocumentTitle title='Workshop Booker'>
                <div className='App'>
                    <Layout {...this.props} />
                    <hr />
                    {this.props.children}
                </div>
            </DocumentTitle>
        );
    }
}
```

Layout component

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes, findDOMNode } from 'react';
import shouldPureComponentUpdate from 'react-pure-render/function';
import Workshops from './Workshops';

export default class Layout extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        params: PropTypes.shape({
            login: PropTypes.string,
            name: PropTypes.string
        })
    };

    static contextTypes = {
        history: PropTypes.object.isRequired
    };

    shouldComponentUpdate = shouldPureComponentUpdate;

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.setState({
            loginOrRepo: parseFullName(nextProps.params)
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className='Explore'>
                    <Workshops />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I have been following this e[xample](http://gaearon.github.io/flux-react-router-example) and mainly my structure follows the idea behind but the thing is that all inherited components are warpped as child. How do I generate the structure to open a new view?

but

Comment: What precisely is being wrapped that you don't want wrapped?

Comment: I have each time all the items wrapped under the list on slug  and under I have the clicked item. Desired have a new view without all items

Comment: Where are all the items being rendered? It doesn't appear to be in the code you posted. Is that the complete listing?

Comment: I added my Layout component, this component is getting called on boot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want a view to be wrapped in another, then don't nest the views in the component or in the route setup. The Route config might look like this instead:

```js
render() {
  const { history } = this.props;
  return (
    <Router history={history}>
      <Route component={App}>
        <Route component={Layout}>
          <Route path='/' component={Workshops} />
          <Route path='/:slug' component={Workshop} />
        </Route>
      </Route>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Then you'd also change `App` and `Layout` so that they don't render fixed components, but instead render their children:

```js
// App

render() {
    return (
        <DocumentTitle title='Workshop Booker'>
            <div className='App'>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        </DocumentTitle>
    );
}

// Layout

render() {
    return (
        <div className='Explore'>
                {this.props.children}
        </div>
    );
}
```

If you need to render more than one dynamic thing in a view, you can use the [multiple components configuration](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#components-1).